# Does anyone know how to conditionally set the fieldsets?

Tags: fieldset

I use fieldsets in my admin panel to group/title my related fields.
This works great in superuser.  When I log in as staff, which has some fields excluded I get an error.

***Caught KeyError while rendering: Key 'A' not found in Form***

In the simple example below if i'm a super user all works great.
If i log in as a staff user thus the code exclude A fieldset I get the
the error:

models.py:

class Cars(models.Model):
    A = models.CharField('A', ...)
    B = models....
    C = models...
    D = models...

admin.py:

class CarsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fieldsets = (_('first group'},{'fields'sad('A','B'),('C','D'),)})
      def get_form(self,request,obj=None, **kwargs):
          self.exclude = []
          if not request.user.is_superuser:
               self.exclude.append('A')
          return super(CarAdmin,self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)

Bottom line is I want to maintain the grouping offered by fieldsets.

Does anyone know how to conditionally set the fieldsets??

Comment: Please, format your code and some tags, like django, python, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `A` field from `self.fieldsets` as well, when adding it to `self.exclude`.